# How to execute if condition based on a value from query string in JavaScript/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, query-string, querystringparameter

I've a variable called url as follows :

```
url = "http://56.177.59.250/static/ajax.php?core[ajax]=true&core[call]=prj_name.contactform&width=400&core[security_token]=c7854c13380a26ff009a5cd9e6699840"
```

Now I want to use `if condition` only if `core[call]` is equal to the value it currently has i.e. `prj_name.contactform` otherwise not.

How should I do this since the parameter from query-string is in array format?

Comment: parse query string, look for value.  I dont quite see the problem here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `String.indexOf` and check if it is present (that is not `-1`, which means it doesn't exist)

```
if(url.indexOf("core[call]=prj_name.contactform") > -1){
   // valid. Brew some code here
}
```

Comment: i like this.  It is simple.  No need to convert and create a plethora of complicated objects, therefore it doesn't take up extra space, and only scans once, unlike parsers which will need to scan repetitively for keywords like '?' or '&'.  This i feel is the best, and straightforward approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **location.search** :

```
 <script>
function get(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
if(get("core[call]") == "prj_name.contactform"){
    alert('ok');
}else{
    alert('no');
}
</script>
```